# Use Generic when return values vary depending on the conditions

Tags: java, spring, generics, return

I'd like to change the return value according to the conditions without using the object. How I can do that with Generics (if possible)?

```
public Object getABC(SearchVO sVO) throws Exception {

    if(sVO.getNo() != null && sVO.getNo() != 0) {
        return service.one(sVO);   // return not list
    } else {
        return service.list(sVO);  // return list Type
    }
}
```

Comment: How would the caller know at compile time what the data will be at run time? Think about it.

Comment: @GhostCat : Oh Sorry, I forgot that. :)

Comment: @GhostCat : I think he was. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, and not a good idea!

X and "list of X" aren't the same type, and there is no way to express that using generics either. You see, generics are a compile time concept. Generics don't play much of a role at runtime. Thus a potential caller would not even know at compile time what will come back.

And more importantly: this is also not good design practice.  A caller should know what comes back, otherwise you put the burden on each caller of that method to distinguish the various possible results.

Thus, the real answer: simply always return a list. In one case, with one element, otherwise with more elements! (or, to be precise: in the second case, you simply don't know how many elements will be coming back, 0, 1, 42, who knows).

Comment: Always returning the list is simply perfect solution. UpVote for that.